# trigger rowcommand event from commandfrield Edit button

Tags: asp.net

I have a query regarding GridView Control : I added a commandfield inside my Gridview and set `ShowEditButton="True"` (By default it trigger RowEditing Event). Can i Trigger `RowCommand Event` Instead of `RowEditing Event`.

I know i can do it via other way but just got curious whether we can do this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you would need to use a control like [ButtonField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.aspx) or [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) in order to trigger a custom command.